# Making Oauth2 request with Java, Spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I have tried googling but i haven't found a good guide that can help me. I want to make a request towards the site Wunderlist.com but i don't know how to make the request and save the token.

According to the Wunderlist documentation i should make a request that looks like this.

https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=ID&redirect_uri=URL&state=RANDOM

This will return a login page for the user, the user accepts and is then redirected to my site and i will get a token in return. But i don't know how to save the token.

Copypasted from Wunderlist API documentation.

1. Redirect users to request Wunderlist access
2. Wunderlist redirects back to your site
   If the user accepts your request, Wunderlist will redirect to your redirect_uri with a temporary code in a code parameter as well as the state you provided in the previous step in a state parameter. If the states don't match, the request has been created by a third party and the process should be aborted.

Exchange code for an access token

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a `client_id`, you should also have registered a `callback_url` at Wunderlist. After the user authenticates itself at Wunderlist, your callback will be called by Wunderlist with the user's credentials.
Normally there would also be an endpoint at Wunderlist you can call to retrieve the credentials given the token presented by the user when he returns to the `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Ah, so in my application i should have Getmapping  that accepts a call from Wunderlist, and that will save the token? How do i save tokens? What object type. Thank you!

Comment: Your own mapping if you implement oauth yourself, or use the spring security library. The returned object is custom to Wunderlist.